# Error on heroku when denied privilidges on Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, devise, mobile-fu

I got a strange error in application. It happens when I try to sign in with facebook, and than on facebook deny app the privileges that it asks for.

Here's stack trace:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state=426366bb3ac72ca4ad2b8b3fea5d5c7f628d6463b5df64a6" for 95.51.182.141 at 2013-09-05 20:55:24 +0000
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
Parameters: {"error"=>"access_denied", "error_code"=>"200", "error_description"=>"Permissions error", "error_reason"=>"user_denied", "state"=>"426366bb3ac72ca4ad2b8b3fea5d5c7f628d6463b5df64a6"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass):
   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mobile-fu-1.1.1/lib/mobile-fu.rb:165:in `mobile_exempt?'
   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mobile-fu-1.1.1/lib/mobile-fu.rb:114:in `set_mobile_format'
   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mobile-fu-1.1.1/lib/mobile-fu.rb:89:in `set_request_format'
(...)
```

What's funny is that when I looked into mobile-fu code I saw that what's nil (and apparently shouldn't be) is `params[:action]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged bit deeper and it seams that devise works funny that way, that sometimes params[:action] isn't set. Anyways it's an issue on divise <-> mobile-fu line, or that's what it seams.

Here's an issue on github (which is now closed):

https://github.com/benlangfeld/mobile-fu/issues/22#issuecomment-26775053

The fix isn't what I would wish for, but perhaps there is a reason why params[:action] (and params[:controller]) isn't set